# kafkaTemplate in Transactional kafkalistener publishes messages when transaction is rolled back

Tags: kotlin, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am test out exactly-once delivery with spring-kafka. My understanding is that the offsets and any messages published through kafkaTemplate will be part of the same transaction.

However, then i throw an exception after publishing, even though the consumer offset is not commited, the messages are still publish.

Is there something wrong in my setup? Also do I need to set @transaction on each kafkalistener class? when i removed it I saw transactions being created in spring-kafka debug logs.

```
@Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager")
@KafkaListener(
        id = "\${messaging.command.consumer-group-id}",
        clientIdPrefix = "\${messaging.command.consumer-group-id}",
        topics = ["\${messaging.command.topic}"],
        concurrency = "\${messaging.command.listener-count}"
    )
    fun processCommand1(@Payload command: EntityCommand<JsonNode>, record: ConsumerRecord<String, Array<Byte>>) {
        testEventPublisher.publish(record.key(), "test")
        testEventPublisher.publish(randomUUID().toString(), "test)
       throw RuntimeException("test")
    }
```

Publisher (I added the executeInTransaction() while trying to get it to work properly):

```
class TransactionalTopicPublisher<TYPE>(val kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, Any>, val topic: String) {

    fun publish(key: String, message: TYPE) {
        kafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction {
            kafkaTemplate.send(
                topic,
                key,
                message
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Producer config:

```
@Bean
    fun kafkaTemplate(producerFactory: ProducerFactory<String, Any>): KafkaTemplate<String, Any> {
        return KafkaTemplate(producerFactory)
    }

    @Bean(KAFKA_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
    fun kafkaTransactionManager(kafkaProducerFactory: ProducerFactory<String, Any>): KafkaTransactionManager<String, Any> {
        val kafkaTransactionManager = KafkaTransactionManager<String, Any>(kafkaProducerFactory)
        return kafkaTransactionManager
    }

    @Bean
    fun kafkaProducerFactory(kafkaJsonSerializer: JsonSerializer<Any>): ProducerFactory<String, Any> {
        val factory = DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, Any>(producerConfig())
        factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix)
        factory.setValueSerializer(kafkaJsonSerializer)
        return factory
    }

    @Bean
    fun producerConfig(): Map<String, Any> {
        return mapOf(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG to bootstrapServers,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to StringSerializer::class.java.name,
            ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG to true,
            ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION to 1,
            ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG to "all",
            ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG to 16384,
            ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG to 1,
            ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG to 33554432,
            ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG to ProducerInterceptor::class.java.name
        )
    }

    @Bean
    fun kafkaJsonSerializer(kafkaObjectMapper: ObjectMapper): JsonSerializer<Any> {
        val jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer<Any>(kafkaObjectMapper)
        jsonSerializer.isAddTypeInfo = false
        return jsonSerializer
    }
```

Consumer Config:

```
@Bean
    fun kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
        kafkaTransactionManager: KafkaTransactionManager<String, Any>,
        stringJsonMessageConverter: StringJsonMessageConverter
    ): ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> {
        val factory = ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>()
        factory.consumerFactory = consumerFactory()
        factory.setMessageConverter(stringJsonMessageConverter)
        factory.setErrorHandler(messagingErrorHandler())
        factory.containerProperties.transactionManager = kafkaTransactionManager
        return factory
    }

    @Bean
    fun stringJsonMessageConverter(kafkaObjectMapper: ObjectMapper) =
        StringJsonMessageConverter(kafkaObjectMapper)

    @Bean
    fun messagingErrorHandler() =
        MessagingErrorHandler()

    @Bean
    fun consumerFactory(): ConsumerFactory<String, Any> {
        val consumerFactory = DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Any>(consumerConfig())
        return consumerFactory
    }

    @Bean
    fun consumerConfig(): Map<String, Any> {
        return mapOf(
            ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG to bootstrapServers,

            ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to StringDeserializer::class.java.name,
            ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG to StringDeserializer::class.java.name,

            ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG to IsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT),
            ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG to false,
            ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG to "earliest",
            ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG to MAX_POLL_RECORD,

            ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG to ConsumerInterceptor::class.java.name,

            JsonDeserializer.USE_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS to false
        )
    }
```

OffsetCommittingAndDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer:

```
@Transactional(KAFKA_TRANSACTION_MANAGER)
class OffsetCommittingAndDeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(val template: KafkaTemplate<Any, Any>) :
    DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template) {

    override fun accept(record: ConsumerRecord<*, *>, exception: Exception) {
        super.accept(record, exception)

        val topicPartition = TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition())
        val offsetAndMetadata = OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() +1)

        template.executeInTransaction {
            template.sendOffsetsToTransaction(
                mapOf(topicPartition to offsetAndMetadata)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not add `@Transactional` to the listener; the container starts the transaction. Try enabling DEBUG logging for `o.s.transaction` and `o.s.kafka` to see if it helps you figure out what's going on. You should not see the records with READ_COMMITTED isolation. The records will be in the log, but the consumer should skip over them.

Comment: Thanks i'll try it out. The behaviour i am expecting is possible?, right? Messages shouldn't be published right?

Comment: They will be published but read_committed consumers won't see them. You will see them in a console-consumer.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it out. Do I need to publish within executeInTransaction?

Comment: No. That will publish in a separate transaction.

Comment: Seems like it's committing the offset at the end. I wonder if it's because of the DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor marking the record after maxRetries

Comment: The container commits no offsets when using transactions. The offset is sent to the transaction which is committed or rolled back.

Comment: ok my bad, error handler was swallowing exception. Working as expected now

Comment: actually.. just realised that when i restart the app, it picks up published the published messages that were part of the rolled back transaction

Comment: Makes no sense. If a tx rolls back, any published messages within that tx are not visible to a read_committed consumer. So something else is at play.

Comment: I lost the read_committed while refactoring. What I noticed though is that when I restart the application, it reprocesses the failed message in the consumer topic. Not sure if this is the expected behaviour.

DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor is using seek to skip the record. Do I need to implement my own AfterRollbackProcessor that just commits the offset?

Comment: I got the behaviour I expect by extending the recoverer to commit the offset (see code above). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Don't use `executeInTransaction` you want to send the offsets to the same transaction the dead-letter was published in. Please open an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues). The framework should have an option to do this without having to write your own code.

Comment: Thanks, I created a ticket.